# Turning single objects into object array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, emoji

I have a react application, that uses the emoji-mar node module. And I'm trying to make it so a user can add Emojis to user comments.

SO I have a class based 'comment' component, and I have made it work with only one emoji so far.

I have commented my so far solution to array-based solution in the code:

```
  constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state ={
  loading: false,
  showModal: false,
  showEmoji: false,
  //emoji: []
  emoji: {
      id: '',
      count: 1
  }
}

//executed, when a user picks an emoji, the emoji object is sent in as parameter
addEmoji = (emoji) =>{
console.log(emoji.id)
console.log(this.state.emoji.id)
if(emoji.id === this.state.emoji.id){
this.increment(emoji)
}else{
let selectedEmoji = {
    id: emoji.id,
    count: 1
}
this.setState({
  emoji: selectedEmoji,
  showEmoji: true
})
console.log(this.state.emoji)
}
```

}

I also have a method to increment, the count property on the emoji object, so if an emoji is picked more then once it will increment

```
  increment = (emoji) =>{
  console.log(emoji.id)
  console.log(this.state.emoji.id)
  console.log(this.state.emoji.count)
  let newEmoji = {...this.state.emoji}
  newEmoji.count = this.state.emoji.count+1
  console.log(newEmoji.count)
 this.setState(   
   {emoji: newEmoji}
 )
 console.log(this.state.emoji.count)
}
```

and my conditional render, where I display my emojis

```
 {this.state.showEmoji && this.state.emoji != null &&
        <div className="emoji">
        {/*{emojis}*/}
        {
        <Emoji onClick={this.increment} tooltip={true}
        emoji={{id: this.state.emoji.id, skin: 1}} size={25} />}
        <p>{this.state.emoji.count}</p>
        </div>
        }
```

I tried using the map function to map the emoji into a variable, but it gave the error

```
this.state.emoji.map is not a function

let emojis = this.state.emoji.map( (emoji, index) =>{
  return <Emoji onClick={this.increment} tooltip={true}
  emoji={{id: emoji.id, skin: 1}} size={25}  />
})
```

even though I declared it an array. I'm suspecting, that since the array is empty initially, it does not have an object to work within the addEmoji function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this.state.emoji.map is not a function**

that's right it is object... because trows this error

if you need add new object on the array do this

for example(this is only for demonstration)

```
  state = {
    emoji: []
  };

  addEmojiHandler = () => {
    let emoji = {
      id: "1",
      count: 1
    };

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      emoji: [...prevState.emoji, emoji]
    }));
  };
```

Comment: I see that makes sense, but would it only give this error if the array is empty?

Comment: this error throwing because object has not map method... you ttring map object in this example... just check like this (this.state.emoji && do map here)

your code is unclear sorry ...

Comment: so i should map inside the render method, and not make a seperate variable?

Comment: try without variable  {this.state.emoji && this.state.emoji.map(...)}